# File type icon in the title bar in osx

Tags: osx

I'm using emacs I downloaded from http://emacsformacosx.com/, but it doesn't display the file type icon for some file types like plain text file, in the title bar. How can I make it appear?

What I mean by "file type icon" is like the blue c++ icon in the title bar of the frame in [this picture](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/e6277aaf0447ba8d835cb27dcd1eb84f72925b26/68747470733a2f2f7261772e6769746875622e636f6d2f436f72736169722f656d6163732d64657669616e742d7468656d652f6d61737465722f73686f742d302e706e67)